# Turning a plain JS Object into a reactive one

Tags: meteor

I am working on an edit form that has two paths.  One is when the user clicks a "New" button, the other is when they click "Edit".

When they click "New", the code sets a `form_id` Session var to null and a `client_id` session variable to null, then does a `Router.go('formEdit')` to load the formEdit template/route.

In the formEdit.js, I do a reactive Template helper (I think that's what they are called, but anyway) like so:

```
Template.formEdit.form = function() {
    var form;
    if (Session.equals('form_id', null)) {
        // Create empty form
        form = {
            title: null,
            client_id: Session.get('client_id'),
            header_fields: [],
            form_fields: []
        };
    } else {
        // Load form
        form = Forms.findOne({_id: Session.get('form_id')});
    }

    return form;
}
```

Basically I check if the `form_id` was set or not, if so I load it from the Forms collection, if not I create a blank one.  I thought this would be pretty simple, really.

The problem is that the created/found `form` object does not behave in a "reactive" way.  If I add `header_fields` or `form_fields` the subsequent template code never updates.  Both are in a `{{#each}}` like so:

```
<template name="formEdit">
    ...
    {{#each header_fields}}
        {{> headerFieldOutput}}
    {{/each}}
    ...
    {{#each form_fields}}
        {{> formFieldOutput}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

How do I make it such that I can push `header_fields` and `form_fields` onto the form and have the underlying template reactively update the `{{#each}}`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about it a little differently than what the reactive programming methodology in Meteor is expecting.

You're putting the 'display' logic in your template helper, rather than using the template scaffolding itself to do it.

So, declare a very simple template helper, something like this:

```
Template.formEdit.form = function () {
  return forms.findOne(Session.get("form_id"));
};
```

And then, in your template scaffolding have something like this:

```
{{#if form}}
 {{#with form}}
  {{#each header_fields}}
   etc...
 {{/with}}
{{#else}}
  [[insert your blank form scaffolding in here]]...
{{/if}}
```

Then, as you set your Session `form_id` variable, you can set it to null to invoke the `{{#else}}` portion.

There are more details than this (logic in the form submit click handler to identify if you are performing an update or an insert, for example) but hopefully you get the gist of it from this.

You should try to [gain a better understanding](http://manual.meteor.com/) about how cursors and reactive computations work, as it will help you better understand how to best use the reactive methodology. A good starting place is the [parties](https://www.meteor.com/examples/parties) example (watch the video and walk through the code manually). It's similar to what you're doing, and shows a good way of building your templates for when you don't have a 'selected' object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will read through the manual again and re-evaluate what I am trying to do.  I guess I still have a lot of confusion surrounding how reactivity works and what triggers it.  My goal here was to have a form that supported both editing an existing or new 'form', which in itself has header/form fields that I want to provide via in-line editing.  Not sure how your example will work when the {{#else}} triggers, and the in-line edited portions will need something to "attach" too.  Guess I need to read some more...

Comment: You'll get it! It will just 'click' one day, I promise. the `#else` is basically a copy of what you have in your #if, but it's not attached to a form, because you don't need to have a form until you submit, if that makes sense. So, when form is null, the `#else` triggers. Keep going, it'll make sense soon!